# Simple bash function to find/replace string variable (no files)

Tags: bash, shell

I simply want a function (or just a 1-liner) to find/replace a string inside a variable, and not worry if the variables contain crazy characters.

Pseudo-code:

```
findReplace () {
  #what goes here?
}

myLongVar="some long \crazy/ text my_placeholder bla"

replace="my_placeholder"
replaceWith="I like hamburgers/fries"

myFinalVar=$(findReplace $myLongVar $replace $replaceWith)
```

All similar questions seem complicated and use files

Comment: bash's Parameter Expansion might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the function like this:

```
findReplace1() {
    printf "%s" "${1/"$2"/$3}"
}
```

And then run it like this:

```
myFinalVar=$(findReplace "$myLongVar" "$replace" "$replaceWith")
```

Note the double-quotes -- they're very important, because without them bash will split the variables' values into separate words (e.g. `"some long \crazy/ text..."` -> `"some" "long" "\crazy/" "text..."`) and also try to expand anything that looks like a wildcard into a list of matching filenames. It's ok to leave them off on the right side of an assignment (`myFinalVar=...`), but that's one of the few places where it's ok. Also, note that within the function I put double-quotes around `$2` -- in that case again it's to keep it from being treated as a wildcard pattern, but here it'd a string-match wildcard rather than filenames. Oh, and I used `printf "%s"` instead of `echo` because some versions of `echo` do weird things with strings that contain backslashes and/or start with "-".

And, of course, you can just skip the function and do the replacement directly:

```
myFinalVar=${myLongVar/"$replace"/$replaceWith}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myFinalVar=${myLongVar/$replace/$replaceWith}
```

If your want to replace all occurrences of `$replace`, not just the first, use:

```
myFinalVar=${myLongVar//$replace/$replaceWith}
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> **Pattern substitution.**  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern
>   just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is expanded and the longest
>   match of pattern against  its               value  is  replaced  with 
>   string.   If pattern begins with /, all matches of pattern are
>   replaced with string.  Normally only the first match is replaced.  If
>   pattern               begins with #, it must match at the beginning of
>   the expanded value of parameter.  If pattern begins with %, it must
>   match at the end of the expanded value of  parameter.  If string is
>   null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may
>   be omitted.  If the `nocasematch` shell option is enabled, the match is
>   performed               without regard to the case of alphabetic
>   characters.  If parameter is @ or *, the substitution operation is
>   applied to each  positional  parameter  in  turn,  and  the
>   expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with @ or *, the substitution operation is applied to each
>   member of the array in turn,              and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.